# What should be the logic to find minimum clock angle?

Tags: c

[image: Details of taking input and output]
My code is below it worked fine for sample test case but didn't get accepted in final submission.The program is asking to do this.
There are 360 Longitudes on the Earth, which are equidistant vertical imaginary lines drawn on the Earth, separated by 1 degree each from center of the Earth. Period of the rotation of the Earth on its axis is 24 hours. All countries have their own official times and hence time zones.

UTC is universal time coordinate which passes through 0 (Zero degree) longitude.

Time at a particular location on Earth can be calculated using period of the rotation of Earth and longitude of that particular location. For example, Indian time zone IST (Indian standard Time) is located at 82.5° E longitude. Hence, Indian time can be calculated as below:-

IST = UTC + (24/360)*82.5 = UTC + 5:30Hrs

Now suppose we changed period of rotation of the earth using some imaginary power, this will change the time at every longitude on the earth.

Calculate the smallest angle between hour and minute hand of the clock , which shows the difference of time at a particular longitude and the time at UTC  i.e. we have to take smaller of the two angle formed between hour and minute hand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
int p;
float l;
float t,m,mang,hang,and;
int i;
scanf("%d",&p);
scanf("%f",&l);
l= floor(100*l)/100; 
t=(p/360.0)*l;
i=(int)t;
m=((t-i)*60);
mang=(m/5)*30;
if(i>=1&&i<=11){
hang=(i*30)+(((t-i)*60)/2);
}
else
hang=0+(((t-i)*60)/2);
if(mang>=hang)
{
ang=mang-hang;
}
else
{
ang=hang-mang;
}
if(((i>6&&i<=11)&&m==0.0)||ang>180.0)
{
 ang=360-ang;
}
printf("%0.2f",ang);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be lack of precision.

For example, for input `p=1` and `l=0.01`, your code prints `0.05`. Just changing data type of variables from float to double, the output becomes `0.06`. Considering that the right answer is `0.055` in this case, you should be printing `0.06`.

Answer (score -1):

Check this, it may help you:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
       int n =sc.nextInt();
       float l =sc.nextFloat();
       float t=((float)n/360)*l;
       int h=(int)t;
       float d=(t-h)*60;
       int m=(int)d;
       //System.out.println(h);
       //System.out.println(m);
       int ha = ((h*60)+m)/2;
       int ma= m*6;
       float angle=Math.abs(ha-ma);
       if(angle>180)
           System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",360-angle));
       else 
           System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",angle));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to your answer rather than just code.